# Mailchimp repeatable blocks issue

Tags: html-email, markup, mailchimp

I have next table in my template:

```
<table ...>
    <tr mc:repeatable mc:hideable>
        <td mc:edit="mc-news-item-image"><a href="#"><img .../></a></td>
        <td mc:edit="mc-news-item-h3"><h3>Lorem ipsum.</h3></td>
        <td mc:edit="mc-news-item-date"><span>22.10.13</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In edit campaign mode if I try to dublicate a row I get copy of it but can't edit any block in template. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Mailchimp doesn't allow the hideable and repeatable tags to be on the same table/div.

So you are going to have to use one or the other.